# Problem with TouchableOpacity, negative margin and Android - React Native

Tags: android, react-native, margin, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I'm with a problem with TouchableOpacity and Negative Margins inside a FlatList. On iOS works well, but on Android, when I click at the TouchableOpacity in the front of other TochableOpacity, the TouchableOpacity from behind fires. I don't know how to solve this.

[iOS Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTUnc.png)

I clicked at "Proposta 70" but fires "Proposta 78" from behind.
[Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHnNR.png)

The FlatList code

```
<View style={styles.containerList}>
    <FlatList
      data={proposalsList}
      keyExtractor={item => item.proposta_id}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
        <RenderItem
          item={item}
          index={index}
          isLoweredCard={
            openedCardIndex !== null && index === openedCardIndex + 1
          }
          changeOpenedCardIndex={changeOpenedCardIndex}
        />
      )}
      refreshing={loading}
      onRefresh={() => getProposalsAndNotifications()}
    />
  </View>
```

The RenderItem code

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.container(index, isLoweredCard)}
  onPress={() => changeOpenedCardIndex(index)}
>
  <>
    <View
      style={[
        styles.lineContainer,
        { marginBottom: metrics.padding * 1.5 },
      ]}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: '50%',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.proposalId}>
          {`Proposta ${item.proposta_id}`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.proposalDate}>
          {dayjs(item?.proposta_data_criacao).format('DD.MM.YYYY')}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'flex-end',
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.statusContainer}>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: wp(4), fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
            <TypeStatus status={item?.proposta_status} />
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor solicitado</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_financiado)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor liberado</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_financiado)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Parcelas</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {`${item?.proposta_valor_prazo}x`}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.lineContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailLabel}>Valor da parcela</Text>
      <Text style={styles.proposalDetailValue}>
        {formatCurrency(item?.proposta_valor_parcela)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={goToDetails}
        title="Ver detalhes"
        titleStyle={styles.proposalButtonText}
        style={styles.button}
      />
    </View>
  </>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

And the style of items

```
import {
widthPercentageToDP as wp,
heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

import { metrics, colors } from '../../../../constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: (index, isLoweredCard) => ({
 backgroundColor: `#00${index}F${index}C`,
 marginTop: !isLoweredCard && index !== 0 ? -wp(53) : metrics.padding,
 marginHorizontal: metrics.padding,
 alignContent: 'center',
 padding: metrics.padding,
 borderRadius: metrics.radius,
 zIndex: -(index + 999),
}),
lineContainer: {
 width: '100%',
 justifyContent: 'space-between',
 flexDirection: 'row',
 marginBottom: metrics.padding / 2,
},
statusContainer: {
 backgroundColor: colors.white,
 borderRadius: 20,
 width: '70%',
 paddingVertical: 3,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
},
proposalId: {
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(4.5),
},
proposalDate: {
 color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(3.5),
},
proposalDetailLabel: {
 fontSize: wp(4),
 color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)',
},
proposalDetailValue: {
 fontSize: wp(4.5),
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
},
proposalButtonText: {
 color: colors.white,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: wp(4),
},
button: {
 borderRadius: metrics.radius,
 backgroundColor: '#002F6C',
 paddingHorizontal: metrics.padding * 3,
},
buttonContainer: {
 width: '100%',
 marginTop: metrics.padding,
 alignItems: 'center',
},
});

export default styles;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered exactly the same problem on Android. [My `FlatList` rendered items with negative margin to superimpose them on each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0tVI.jpg). The touchable on iOS is perfect but on Android it press the lowest item behind.

Finally I solved this by replacing

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
```

with

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Using `react-native` **0.63.4** and `react-native-gesture-handler` **1.9.0** in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution for my case was inverting the negative margin (top / bottom).

In my case the View component was with negative marginBottom and the touchable part that I wanted was on the bottom as well, so I inverted it and put the View inside the next component and gave a negative marginTop. So the part that I wanted to be touchable worked fine.

A little strange but for me it worked out well...